# Meaning of a 1.9 (e) (Real and Complex Analysis of Walter Rudin)

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

$\textbf{1.9 (c)}$  If *f* is a complex measurable function on X, there is a complex measurable function $\alpha$ on X such that |$\alpha$| = 1 and *f* = $\alpha$| *f* | .

What this mean? and, what is $\alpha$?

(This is my first approach to this book)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that for any complex number $z=a+ib$, $\overline{z}z=|z|^2$, where $\overline{z}=a-ib$.

Set $a(x)=\frac{|f(x)|}{\overline{f(x)}}$ if $f(x)\neq0$ and $1$ otherwise.

if $f(x)\neq0$ then
$a(x)|f(x)|=\frac{|f(x)|^2}{\overline{f(x)}}=\frac{\overline{f(x)}f(x)}{\overline{f(x)}}=f(x)$

The measurability of $a$ is not hard to prove. I leave the details to the OP.